# Breeze: how to increase maximum length of string in entity

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to save images as base64 strings to server DB using breeze.
It does work for small images but doesn't work if base64 string exceeds some limit.

I have tried to change maxlength in metadata to bigger vulues but it din't solve the problem:

```
{ "name": "Base64String", "type": "Edm.String", "maxLength": "9000000", "fixedLength": "false", "unicode": "true" }
```

is there a way to increase characters limit?

Comment: This might depend upon your database server.  Which one are you using?  Are you saving in a varchar field, or a blob?

Comment: @Steve Schmitt, it's varchar field on sql server

Comment: Is the DB field defined as varchar(MAX), or some smaller limit?  What seems to be the limit that you hit?